# elements of the fundamental group and closed geodesics?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $(M;g)$ be a closed manifold . fix a point $x$ in $M$ and denote by $G=\pi_1(M;x)$ now let $\alpha$ in G i have 2 questions :

1- can  $\alpha$ be represented by a closed geodesic ?

2- can $\alpha $ be represented by a closed minimizing geodesic ?

Comment: i know 1 is true for free homotopy classes and i guess 2 is true also

Comment: 2 can't be true if the loop in $\pi_1$ can only be represented by a self-intersecting curve, which happens frequently.